# Using ARCore for Measurment

Tags: google-play, arcore

I would like to know if it is possible to measure the dimensions of an object by just pointing the camera at the object without moving the camera from left to right like we do in Google Measurement.

Answer (score 0):

A depth map cannot be calculated from just a 2D camera image.  A smart phone does not have a distance sensor but it does have motion sensors, so by combining the movement of the device with changes in the input from the camera(s), ARCore can calculate depth.  To put it simply, objects in close to the camera move around on screen more, compared to objects further away.

To get depth data from a fixed position would require different technologies than found on current phones, such as LiDAR or an infrared beam projector and infrared camera.